# Azure Application Insights - Location Issue

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using Resource Manger API to create Application Insight resource in Azure. Steps are like below:

- I create the Resource group in **East US** location
- Then I create the Insights Component under it in **East US** location, which fails. with below error. However, if I create the Component in **Central US** location (which is different from the location of containing Resource group), it succeeds.

  ```
  "error": {
      "code": "MissingRegistrationForLocation",
      "message": "The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in the location 'southcentralus'. Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location."
  }
  ```

Comment: see: azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services .  AI is a "global" service.  Azure requires a location when creating a resource, so for that we're considered "Central US".  But put your resource group, other resources wherever you want them.

Comment: @JohnGardner (Reading pricing info...) So there is never a cross-region charge for getting data into App Insights, correct? What about for getting data out via Continuous Export? Should the storage account chosen for that be in Central US?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for a good source to back my story, but couldn't find the URL anymore :( . As far as I know the Application Insights services are only available from the Central US location. Which can be causing the error, because you are trying to set up an Insights component in the East US region.

[image: Screenshot of my environment when creating a new App Insights instance]

As you can see, the location is locked and therefore it is not possible to choose for East US.

You can keep track of Azure Application Insights service updates at [this page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?service=application-insights). Next to that you can filter the updates only to see [service updates about regions and datacenters.](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?service=application-insights&update-type=regions-and-datacenters)

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: Application Insights is currently deployed in Central-US only however, as the page indicates at the bottom, it operates globally and doesn’t require customers to specify a particular region when using the service. see: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services

Comment: Almost a year later, this info fixed my template deployment failure. The "Location" property is required, but the only valid value is "Central US". I was trying "West US" to match the rest of my deployment. Contrary to what is written elsewhere, "global" doesn't work for the alert rule that goes with the web test.

Comment: This information it is not valid anymore.
Always go to this page to get a list of regions updated.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/regions/services/

Answer (score 3):

Yesterday Microsoft announced general availability in additional regions for Application Insights.

Also, you might run into an error when deploying with your current ARM template!

[Application Insights: General availability in additional regions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/application-insights-general-availability-in-additional-regions-and-resource-location-update-east-us-south-central-us-west-europe-and-north-europe/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was able to resolve the issue by updating Azure within Visual Studio

```
Tools => Extensions And Updates => Updates => Azure*
```